# Where are .exr files listed in Properties dropdowns in Blender?

Tags: properties

city.exr, courtyard.exr, forest.exr, interior.exr, night.exr, studio.exr, sunrise.exr, sunset.exr are shipped with Blender 2.92 and courtyard.exr wants to load by default into a simple refraction construct--it's visible here in the area below the UV skydome I set on top of the XY plane:
[image]

Before I discovered these samples in the Shading top-screen tab, I think I encountered the list of same .exr names elsewhere in the side screen control panels (but I don't remember where).

Therefore my question is where are these .exr files in Properties dropdowns and elsewhere in Blender?

Comment: This probably isn't exactly what you're looking for, but the files themselves are located in the blender folder at `.../2.92/datafiles/studiolights/world`. You can add them as any image or environment texture. Also, you said you're already aware of the selection that appears when you click the sphere in the top right (under where it says "scene world"), correct?

Comment: Thanks for replying, yeah I'm aware of the spheres accessed from clicking under where it says "scene world" but I vaguely recall seeing them lined up one above the other in text string format in a drop-down too, elsewhere in the Blender UI.  Problem: The .exr is showing up as artifact in the object refraction (underneath inside the sky dome).  Visible in attached pic, above, in thread.  One's coral-colored, the other (should it be there at all?) is painted with the forest.exr shading.  Trying to get rid of it.